# Error during migration from npm to yarn - The engine "node" is incompatible with this module

Tags: node.js, npm, migration, yarnpkg

in my project I am trying to migrate **from npm to yarn**.

I simply ran the "**yarn**" command to generate the "**yarn.lock**".

During the process, it showed me the following error:

> error linearicons@1.0.2: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module.

> Expected version "^12.13.0". Got "10.19.0" error Found incompatible module.

So I ran the command "**npm remove linearicons**" then "**yarn**" to generate the "**yarn.lock**" without error, then "**yarn add linearicons**". But it gives me the same error as above.

My **Yarn version is 1.22.10**

**Node version : v10.19.0**

What could I do to fix this problem? I don't understand what he wants

Comment: Update your version of node.js from `10.19.0` to `>=12.13.0`

Answer (score 3):

**Update the node.js version :**

Installation of nvm

```
$ curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.38.0/install.sh | bash
$ source ~/.bashrc
```

Looking for existent versions of node.js

```
$ nvm ls-remote
```

Installation of the last one (as of today)

```
$ nvm install v16.8.0
```

**After that your issue should be fixed.**

Answer (score 3):

```
yarn install --ignore-engines
```

This worked for me, and it was showing this error:

```
 webpack-dev-server@4.5.0: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version ">= 12.13.0". Got "10.19.0"
```

Final result after --ignore-engines

```
success Saved lockfile.
```